# ZonedDateTime to LocalDateTime

Tags: java, datetime-parsing, zoneddatetime, localdatetime

I have a string representing date time with zone and i want to convert the string expression to `LocalDateTime`.

I have tried parsing it into `ZonedDateTime` using `parse` method but failing with an error

```
 @SerializedName("Expires")
 private String expires = "Sat, 13 Jun 2020 23:14:21 GMT";

 public LocalDateTime getExpiredDateTime() {
     return ZonedDateTime.parse(expires).toLocalDateTime();
 }
```

Expected result: a `LocalDateTime` of `2020-06-13T23:14:21`.

Observed result:

> Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException:
>   Text 'Sat, 13 Jun 2020 23:14:21 GMT' could not be parsed at index 0

Comment: show the code that you have tried with some input and output

Comment: @SerializedName("Expires")
    private String expires;


 public LocalDateTime getExpiredDateTime() {
        return ZonedDateTime.parse(expires).toLocalDateTime();
    }

Not Working! please help.

Comment: Provide details as edits to your Question, not comments.

Comment: It seems to me that you shouldn’t want a `LocalDateTime` since your string represents an unambiguous point in time and a `LocalDateTime` cannot do that. Consider `ZonedDateTime` (possibly in your own time zone) or `Instant`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java [provides a formatter](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#RFC_1123_DATE_TIME) for that particular format of input. That format was used in older protocols such as [RFC 1123](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1123) (now supplanted by ISO 8601 in modern protocols).

```
ZonedDateTime
.parse(
    "Sat, 13 Jun 2020 23:14:21 GMT" ,
    DateTimeFormatter. RFC_1123_DATE_TIME
)
.toLocalDateTime()
```

That input is of a poorly-designed legacy format. I suggest educating the publisher of that data about [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

Answer (score 2):

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String dateTimeStr = "Sat, 13 Jun 2020 23:14:21 GMT";
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z");
        ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse(dateTimeStr, formatter);
        System.out.println(zdt);

        LocalDateTime ldt = zdt.toLocalDateTime();
        System.out.println(ldt);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2020-06-13T23:14:21Z[GMT]
2020-06-13T23:14:21
```

**[Update]** [Courtesy Basil Bourque](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62361961/zoneddatetime-to-localdatetime/62362085#comment110292677_62362085)

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String dateTimeStr = "Sat, 13 Jun 2020 23:14:21 GMT";

        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME;

        ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse(dateTimeStr, formatter);
        System.out.println(zdt);

        LocalDateTime ldt = zdt.toLocalDateTime();
        System.out.println(ldt);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2020-06-13T23:14:21Z
2020-06-13T23:14:21
```

Comment: No need for custom formatting pattern: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#RFC_1123_DATE_TIME